# Eclipse RCP: Separators between Toolbars not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the plugin.xml of my application I define several Toolbars, between which I want to have separators. However, if I put `<separator>` elements between them, they don't show up.

What is the reason for this? Is there any workaround how I can display the separators?

This is the toolbar contribution:

```xml
<menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">

  <toolbar
      id="com.myapplication.editors.toolbar">
    <command
        commandId="com.myapplication.editors.open.xml.editor"
        icon="icons/editors/xml.png"
        label="Create XML File "
        style="push">
      <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
        <with
            variable="com.myapplication.editors.command.state.active">
          <equals
              value="ENABLED">
          </equals>
        </with>
      </visibleWhen>
    </command>
    <command
        commandId="com.myapplication.editors.open.text.editor"
        icon="icons/editors/text.png"
        label="Create Plain Text File"
        style="push">
      <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
        <with
            variable="com.myapplication.editors.command.state.active">
          <equals
              value="ENABLED">
          </equals>
        </with>
      </visibleWhen>
    </command>
  </toolbar>

  <separator
      name="com.myapplication.editors.separator1"
      visible="true">
  </separator>

  <toolbar
      id="com.myapplication.editors.parameter.toolbar">
    <command
        commandId="com.myapplication.editors.matrix"
        icon="icons/matrix.png"
        label="Create Matrix"
        style="push">
      <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
        <with
            variable="com.myapplication.editors.command.state.active">
          <equals
              value="ENABLED">
          </equals>
        </with>
      </visibleWhen>
    </command>
        ...
  </toolbar>

</menuContribution>
```

Any idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: Separators only show if there are menu items before and after the separator - is this true in your case?

Comment: With menu items you mean the commands? Then yes. In my example, the separator is in between toolbars (both have commands / items), but I also tried it with putting the separator between the commands of one toolbar, and they still didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions ">
 <toolbar
       id="id.toolbar">
    <command
          commandId="id.command"
          label="Hello World"
          style="push">
    </command>
    <separator
          name="id.separator"
          visible="true">
    </separator>
 </toolbar>
```

Hope above code answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both your way (i.e. declaring the separator as a direct child of the menuContribution) and [yeswanth kumar's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26756856) (i.e. declaring the separator within a toolbar) should work.

It's probably [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413213) bug. Quoting from the bug report:

> [...] It sets false as visible when any sibling has a visible when node or visibility identifier. And it seems to be never updated later.
>
> As a result, separators on toolbar which are contributed through menu contribution are not showing.

So separators currently don't work in combination with `visibleWhen`, unfortunately.